# DumpRegister sometimes blank?

Tags: entanglement, q#

I'm just getting into the baffling world of Quantum Computing so forgive me if this is straightforward...

I'm using Microsoft's Q# simulator so I know I'm allowed to peek into the internals of a Qubit in the way hardware would not allow. Specifically using `DumpRegister()` to look into the Qubit state - however, I think that's not telling me anything about entanglement:

- If I `CNOT` two bits, the `DumpRegister` output is the same before as after, but the state machine must know about that relationship beyond just the current probabilities of values for the register
- If I `MultiplyI` two registers to a third, the `DumpRegister` output is entirely blank, it's not showing any Qubits at all

Is there a way I can get a deeper snapshot view of the machine state? Why is it that `MultiplyI` causes the Qubits to be not reported at all by `DumpRegister`?

Example code:

```
    operation CNot() : Unit
    {
        use reg=Qubit[2];
        ApplyToEachCA(H,reg); 
        DumpRegister((),reg);
        CNOT(reg[0],reg[1]);
        DumpRegister((),reg);
        ResetAll(reg);
    }

    operation Multiply() : Unit
    {
        use r1=Qubit[2];
        use r2=Qubit[2];
        use r3=Qubit[4];

        ApplyToEachCA(H,r1);
        ApplyToEachCA(H,r2);

        for q in r3
        {
            SetQubitState(Zero, q);
        }

        let le1=LittleEndian(r1);
        let le2=LittleEndian(r2);
        let le3=LittleEndian(r3);

        MultiplyI (le1,le2,le3);
    
        DumpRegister ((),r1);
        DumpRegister ((),r2);
        DumpRegister ((),r3);

        let m1=MeasureInteger (le1);
        let m2=MeasureInteger (le2);
        let m3=MeasureInteger (le3);

        Message($"{m1} * {m2} = {m3}");

        ResetAll(r1);
        ResetAll(r2);
        ResetAll(r3);
    }
```

`CNot()` produces `0.500000 +  0.000000 i` for each value before and after - I can see `DumpRegister()` is just showing the probabilities of values in the register which I guess is the same before and after, but there's some other state it's not showing. `DumpMachine()` is no more informative.

`Multiply()` produces an output like `3 * 2 = 6` but each `DumpRegister()` line only produces a blank line.

Comment: Can you provide the complete code snippets you're using and the output you're getting in the CNOT scenario? There can be valid reasons for that - for example, if you're applying CNOT to two newly allocated qubits without anything else, the state before and after will be |00⟩, so the DumpRegister output would be expected to be the same.

Comment: Fair point, I've added code examples - you can see all Qubits are in superposition before the operations

Answer (score 1):

The CNOT behavior is exactly as expected - try applying the CNOT gate to the state $1/2(|00⟩+|01⟩+|10⟩+|11⟩)$ mathematically and you'll see that the resulting state is exactly the same as the pre-CNOT state. (I recommend using Ry gates instead of H to prepare initial states when you're experimenting with gates, it is a lot harder to see the results of a lot of operations like CNOT or X when you start with equal superpositions.)

For `MultiplyI`, the registers will end up entangled after multiplication, and `DumpRegister` can only report states of qubit registers that are not entangled with any other qubits. If you use `DumpMachine` to print the state of the whole system, you'll see the complete combined state and will be able to verify that it's indeed entangled.